# RestKit Shredding JSON Object nodes into Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I have a JSON structure that needs to be shredded into several core data tables.  However with the JSON I am getting back isn't really normalized to a structure I can figure out how to split them into objects.  I have 4 tables, Songs, Artist, Album, Genre.

JSON:

```
{
"Songs": [
{
"strFileID": "b7eccc27-b099-4ea2-93c5-5004f6d2e31d",
"strFileName": "07-Cryin.mp3",
"strDuration": "00:05:09.812",
"strAlbumTitle": "Big Ones",
"strArtists": "Aerosmith",
"strTrackNumber": 7,
"strGenre": "Rock",
"strTitle": "07-Cryin.mp3"
}
]
}
```

Since strArtists isn't split into it's own object and is just an element, I can't figure out how to create the mapping to ensure only "Aerosmith" is ripped out into it's own table and then related back.

Currently I have the following as a starting point to just get song and the artist:

```
    RKManagedObjectMapping *artistMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Artist class]];
    artistMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = ArtistAttributes.artistName;
    [artistMapping mapKeyPath:@"Song.strArtists" toAttribute:ArtistAttributes.artistName];

    RKManagedObjectMapping *songMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Song class]];
    songMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = SongAttributes.fileId;
    [songMapping mapKeyPath:@"strFileID" toAttribute:SongAttributes.fileId];
    [songMapping mapKeyPath:@"strFileName" toAttribute:SongAttributes.fileName];
    [songMapping mapKeyPath:@"strTitle" toAttribute:SongAttributes.title];
    [songMapping mapKeyPath:@"strDuration" toAttribute:SongAttributes.duration];
    [songMapping mapKeyPath:@"strTrackNumber" toAttribute:SongAttributes.trackNumber];

    [songMapping mapRelationship:@"artist" withMapping:artistMapping];

    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:songMapping forKeyPath:@"Song"];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:artistMapping forKeyPath:@"strArtists"];
```